# Failed to get the required ADT version number from the SDK

Tags: android, eclipse

I got an error in eclipse after upgrading Android studio to 2.3 and SDK Tools for it.

when opening eclipse I got the following message:

[image: Screenshot]

I've tried many solutions like removing adt, but no fix also trying to copy **traceview.bat** but no fix.

what is the solution for this?

Thanks

Comment: I have read that you need to have different SDK folders. One for Android Studio and another one for Eclipse. To modify Eclipse's folder for SDK you need to go to Window --> Preferences --> Android and change the "Sdk location". I have done that but still no success. To create the "other" sdk I just copied/pasted the original sdk to the new destination, but I am not sure if this is good. I have tried to install it again to the new destination but I cannot find anywhere in the web a SDK installation file. All I found come with Android Studio included. I hope my hint helps you.

Comment: Looks like you're running this on a Mac though. In which case .bat files wouldn't even work.

Answer (score 13):

Android SDK Tools Revision 25.3.0 removes obsolete/deprecated tools, see  [Release Notes](http://tools.android.com/recent/androidsdktoolsrevision2530feb2017)

So probably you will need to use another SDK or try to return removed tools.

You can download older SDK (probably 25.2.5) like this

For windows http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r[rev]-windows.zip
For Linux http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r[rev]-linux.zip
For Mac http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r[rev]-macosx.zip

Comment: Where can I find the latest SDK that works with Eclipse?

Comment: try this dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.5-windows.zip

Comment: Is that the latest sdk that still works as it is with Eclipse?

Comment: ti should be, yes

Comment: it works, thanks. I met this issue when i upgrade Android Studio SDK.